# Basecamp - Creating a private upload

Tags: basecamp

I am trying to create a Private upload using the bcx API.

But for some reason I cannot find, the upload is uploaded successfully but it's not being marked as Private.

The documentation is here:

https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/uploads.md

This is what I am sending:

```
POST https://basecamp.com/1234567/api/v1/projects/1234567/uploads.json HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic ZXJpY0BXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5hbHMuY29tOmdvcmF2ZW5zNTU=
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: mickey@mouse.com
Host: basecamp.com
Content-Length: 198
Expect: 100-continue

{"content":"this was moved from the other account","attachments":[{"token":"af4e7e8e8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX256549ee0010","name":"Final Export_acu-macrrc_2013-01-22.xls"}],"subscribers":null,"private":true}
```

When I send this I get a 201 created response along with additional details... Happy Days!

But, when I look in the Web UI, the "upload" is there but it's not marked as Private.

(I have successfully created other private objects in this project with this user)

Can anyone see anything wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this turned out to be a bug in the API.

it's now been fixed and works as expected.

hth

Trev